# A unit calling wsock32.dll to be adapted for D2009

Tags: delphi, smtp, delphi-2009

Here a unit i can't get working properly on Delphi 2009. I give you the original code that correctly transmit data when compiled with Delphi 2007. Ansifying the code for Delphi 2009 gives me a connection to the server but no data is transmitted and no feedback). Thanks.

```
unit SMTP_Connections2007;
// *********************************************************************
//     Unit Name          : SMTP_Connections                           *
//     Author             : Melih SARICA (Non ZERO)                    *
//     Date               : 01/17/2004                                 *
//**********************************************************************

interface

uses
  Classes, StdCtrls;

const
  WinSock = 'wsock32.dll';
  Internet = 2;
  Stream  = 1;
  fIoNbRead = $4004667F;
  WinSMTP = $0001;
  LinuxSMTP = $0002;

type

  TWSAData = packed record
    wVersion: Word;
    wHighVersion: Word;
    szDescription: array[0..256] of Char;
    szSystemStatus: array[0..128] of Char;
    iMaxSockets: Word;
    iMaxUdpDg: Word;
    lpVendorInfo: PChar;
  end;
  PHost = ^THost;
  THost = packed record
    Name: PChar;
    aliases: ^PChar;
    addrtype: Smallint;
    Length: Smallint;
    addr: ^Pointer;
  end;

  TSockAddr = packed record
    Family: Word;
    Port: Word;
    Addr: Longint;
    Zeros: array[0..7] of Byte;
  end;


function WSAStartup(Version:word; Var Data:TwsaData):integer; stdcall; far; external winsock;
function socket(Family,Kind,Protocol:integer):integer; stdcall; far; external winsock;
function shutdown(Socket,How:Integer):integer; stdcall; far; external winsock;
function closesocket(socket:Integer):integer; stdcall; far; external winsock;
function WSACleanup:integer; stdcall; far; external winsock;
function bind(Socket:Integer; Var SockAddr:TSockAddr; AddrLen:integer):integer; stdcall; far; external winsock;
function listen(socket,flags:Integer):integer; stdcall; far; external winsock;
function connect(socket:Integer; Var SockAddr:TSockAddr; AddrLen:integer):integer; stdcall; far; external winsock;
function accept(socket:Integer; Var SockAddr:TSockAddr; Var AddrLen:Integer):integer; stdcall; far; external winsock;
function WSAGetLastError:integer; stdcall; far; external winsock;
function recv(socket:integer; data:pchar; datalen,flags:integer):integer; stdcall; far; external winsock;
function send(socket:integer; var data; datalen,flags:integer):integer; stdcall; far; external winsock;
function gethostbyname(HostName:PChar):PHost; stdcall; far; external winsock;
function WSAIsBlocking:boolean; stdcall; far; external winsock;
function WSACancelBlockingCall:integer; stdcall; far; external winsock;
function ioctlsocket(socket:integer; cmd: Longint; var arg: longint): Integer; stdcall; far; external winsock;
function gethostname(name:pchar; size:integer):integer; stdcall; far; external winsock;

procedure _authSendMail(MailServer,uname,upass,mFrom,mFromName,mToName,Subject:string;mto,mbody:TStringList);
function ConnectServer(mhost:string;mport:integer):integer;
function ConnectServerwin(mhost:string;mport:integer):integer;
function DisConnectServer:integer;
function Stat: string;
function SendCommand(Command: String): string;
function SendData(Command: String): string;
function SendCommandWin(Command: String): string;
function ReadCommand: string;
function encryptB64(s:string):string;


var
  mconnHandle: Integer;
  mFin, mFOut: Textfile;
  EofSock: Boolean;
  mactive: Boolean;
  mSMTPErrCode: Integer;
  mSMTPErrText: string;
  mMemo: TMemo;

implementation

uses
  SysUtils, Sockets, IdBaseComponent,
  IdCoder, IdCoder3to4, IdCoderMIME, IniFiles,Unit1;

var
  mClient: TTcpClient;

procedure _authSendMail(MailServer, uname, upass, mFrom, mFromName,
  mToName, Subject: string; mto, mbody: TStringList);
var
  tmpstr: string;
  cnt: Integer;
  mstrlist: TStrings;
  RecipientCount: Integer;
begin
  if ConnectServerWin(Mailserver, 587) = 250 then  //port is 587 
  begin
    Sendcommandwin('AUTH LOGIN ');
    SendcommandWin(encryptB64(uname));
    SendcommandWin(encryptB64(upass));
    SendcommandWin('MAIL FROM: ' + mfrom);
    for cnt := 0 to mto.Count - 1 do
      SendcommandWin('RCPT TO: ' + mto[cnt]);
    Sendcommandwin('DATA');
    SendData('Subject: ' + Subject);
    SendData('From: "' + mFromName + '" <' + mfrom + '>');
    SendData('To: ' + mToName);
    SendData('Mime-Version: 1.0');
    SendData('Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="Esales-Order";');
    SendData('     type="text/html"');
    SendData('');
    SendData('--Esales-Order');
    SendData('Content-Type: text/html;');
    SendData('        charset="iso-8859-9"');
    SendData('Content-Transfer-Encoding: QUOTED-PRINTABLE');
    SendData('');
    for cnt := 0 to mbody.Count - 1 do
      SendData(mbody[cnt]);
    Senddata('');
    SendData('--Esales-Order--');
    Senddata(' ');
    mSMTPErrText := SendCommand(crlf + '.' + crlf);
    try
      mSMTPErrCode := StrToInt(Copy(mSMTPErrText, 1, 3));
    except
    end;
    SendData('QUIT');
    DisConnectServer;
  end;
end;


function Stat: string;
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := ReadCommand;
  Result := s;
end;

function EchoCommand(Command: string): string;
begin
  SendCommand(Command);
  Result := ReadCommand;
end;

function ReadCommand: string;
var
  tmp: string;
begin
  repeat
    ReadLn(mfin, tmp);
    if Assigned(mmemo) then
      mmemo.Lines.Add(tmp);
  until (Length(tmp) < 4) or (tmp[4] <> '-');
  Result := tmp
end;

function SendData(Command: string): string;
begin
  Writeln(mfout, Command);
end;

function SendCommand(Command: string): string;
begin
  Writeln(mfout, Command);
  Result := stat;
end;

function SendCommandWin(Command: string): string;
begin
  Writeln(mfout, Command + #13);
  Result := stat;
end;

function FillBlank(Source: string; number: Integer): string;
var
  a: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for a := Length(trim(Source)) to number do
    Result := Result + ' ';
end;

function IpToLong(ip: string): Longint;
var
  x, i: Byte;
  ipx: array[0..3] of Byte;
  v: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  Longint(ipx) := 0;
  i := 0;
  for x := 1 to Length(ip) do
    if ip[x] = '.' then
    begin
      Inc(i);
      if i = 4 then Exit;
    end
  else
  begin
    if not (ip[x] in ['0'..'9']) then Exit;
    v := ipx[i] * 10 + Ord(ip[x]) - Ord('0');
    if v > 255 then Exit;
    ipx[i] := v;
  end;
  Result := Longint(ipx);
end;

function HostToLong(AHost: string): Longint;
var
  Host: PHost;
begin
  Result := IpToLong(AHost);
  if Result = 0 then
  begin
    Host := GetHostByName(PChar(AHost));
    if Host <> nil then Result := Longint(Host^.Addr^^);
  end;
end;

function LongToIp(Long: Longint): string;
var
  ipx: array[0..3] of Byte;
  i: Byte;
begin
  Longint(ipx) := long;
  Result       := '';
  for i := 0 to 3 do Result := Result + IntToStr(ipx[i]) + '.';
  SetLength(Result, Length(Result) - 1);
end;

procedure Disconnect(Socket: Integer);
begin
  ShutDown(Socket, 1);
  CloseSocket(Socket);
end;

function CallServer(Server: string; Port: Word): Integer;
var
  SockAddr: TSockAddr;
begin
  Result := socket(Internet, Stream, 0);
  if Result = -1 then Exit;
  FillChar(SockAddr, SizeOf(SockAddr), 0);
  SockAddr.Family := Internet;
  SockAddr.Port := swap(Port);
  SockAddr.Addr := HostToLong(Server);
  if Connect(Result, SockAddr, SizeOf(SockAddr)) <> 0 then
  begin
    Disconnect(Result);
    Result := -1;
  end;
end;

function OutputSock(var F: TTextRec): Integer; far;
begin
  if F.BufPos <> 0 then
  begin
    Send(F.Handle, F.BufPtr^, F.BufPos, 0);
    F.BufPos := 0;
  end;
  Result := 0;
end;

function InputSock(var F: TTextRec): Integer; far;
var
  Size: Longint;
begin
  F.BufEnd := 0;
  F.BufPos := 0;
  Result := 0;
  repeat
    if (IoctlSocket(F.Handle, fIoNbRead, Size) < 0) then
    begin
      EofSock := True;
      Exit;
    end;
  until (Size >= 0);
  F.BufEnd := Recv(F.Handle, F.BufPtr, F.BufSize, 0);
  EofSock  := (F.Bufend = 0);
end;


function CloseSock(var F: TTextRec): Integer; far;
begin
  Disconnect(F.Handle);
  F.Handle := -1;
  Result   := 0;
end;

function OpenSock(var F: TTextRec): Integer; far;
begin
  if F.Mode = fmInput then
  begin
    EofSock := False;
    F.BufPos := 0;
    F.BufEnd := 0;
    F.InOutFunc := @InputSock;
    F.FlushFunc := nil;
  end
  else
  begin
    F.Mode := fmOutput;
    F.InOutFunc := @OutputSock;
    F.FlushFunc := @OutputSock;
  end;
  F.CloseFunc := @CloseSock;
  Result := 0;
end;

procedure AssignCrtSock(Socket:integer; Var Input,Output:TextFile);
 begin
  with TTextRec(Input) do
  begin
    Handle := Socket;
    Mode := fmClosed;
    BufSize := SizeOf(Buffer);
    BufPtr := @Buffer;
    OpenFunc := @OpenSock;
  end;
  with TTextRec(Output) do
  begin
    Handle := Socket;
    Mode := fmClosed;
    BufSize := SizeOf(Buffer);
    BufPtr := @Buffer;
    OpenFunc := @OpenSock;
  end;
  Reset(Input);
  Rewrite(Output);
 end;

function ConnectServer(mhost: string; mport: Integer): Integer;
var
  tmp: string;
begin
  mClient := TTcpClient.Create(nil);
  mClient.RemoteHost := mhost;
  mClient.RemotePort := IntToStr(mport);
  mClient.Connect;
  mconnhandle := callserver(mhost, mport);
  if (mconnHandle<>-1) then
  begin
    AssignCrtSock(mconnHandle, mFin, MFout);
    tmp := stat;
    tmp := SendCommand('HELO bellona.com.tr');
    if Copy(tmp, 1, 3) = '250' then
    begin
      Result := StrToInt(Copy(tmp, 1, 3));
    end;
  end;
end;

function ConnectServerWin(mhost: string; mport: Integer): Integer;
var
  tmp: string;
begin
  mClient := TTcpClient.Create(nil);
  mClient.RemoteHost := mhost;
  mClient.RemotePort := IntToStr(mport);
  mClient.Connect;
  mconnhandle := callserver(mhost, mport);
  if (mconnHandle<>-1) then
  begin
    AssignCrtSock(mconnHandle, mFin, MFout);
    tmp := stat;
    tmp := SendCommandWin('HELO bellona.com.tr');
    if Copy(tmp, 1, 3) = '250' then
    begin
      Result := StrToInt(Copy(tmp, 1, 3));
    end;
  end;
end;

function DisConnectServer: Integer;
begin
  closesocket(mconnhandle);
  mClient.Disconnect;
  mclient.Free;
end;

function encryptB64(s: string): string;
var
  hash1: TIdEncoderMIME;
  p: string;
begin
  if s <> '' then
  begin
    hash1 := TIdEncoderMIME.Create(nil);
    p := hash1.Encode(s);
    hash1.Free;
  end;
  Result := p;
end;

end.
```

Here some code to give it a try:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
  //  Button1: TButton;
  //  Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  SMTP_Connections2007;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  mto, mbody: TStringList;
  MailServer, uname, upass, mFrom, mFromName,
  mToName, Subject: string;
begin
  mMemo := Memo1; // to output server feedback
  //..........................
  MailServer := 'somename.servername';
  uname := 'username';
  upass := 'password';
  mFrom :=  'someuser@xyz.net';
  mFromName := 'forename surname';
  mToName := '';
  Subject := 'Your Subject';
  //..........................
  mto := TStringList.Create;
  mbody := TStringList.Create;
  try
    mto.Add('destination_emailaddress');
    mbody.Add('Test Mail');
    //Send Mail.................
    _authSendMail(MailServer, uname, upass, mFrom, mFromName, mToName, Subject, mto, mbody);
    //..........................
  finally
    mto.Free;
    mbody.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ansified your code, and tested it with Delphi2009, it works without any problem.  I've managed to send email from gmx.com to mail.google.com.

I did change string to AnsiString, Char to AnsiChar, and PChar to PAnsiChar.

Maybe you simply forgot to ansify Char or PChar?

Answer (score 2):

One thing to consider would be the TCP/IP library [Synapse](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php/download), of which the latest development version in SVN compiles and runs against Delphi 2009 with Unicode and 
has all of the functionality in your unit and can easily perform the steps of your test program.